# Comparing database values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm comparing usernames from two database tables A and B using an "if statement".

Table A is a username sessionid.
Table B contains payment records (username inclusive).

I used double equal (==) sign to check if the usernames are true. If true, let it echo payment details of B and if not let it be false.

I've done that but it only works for the first row (Record 1) entry in table B. It displays the payment details as I wanted but, if I compare with another username in table B, it gives false where as the comparison is true.

```
        if(($row_rsPH['username'] == $row_GHall['pay1'] && empty($row_GHall['confirm1'])) {
            echo $row_GHall['username']."'s Payment Made";
            }
            else {echo "No Payment Made";}
```

I thought about using a single equal sign but it displays the same first row's record (Record 1) even if i compare with another username in table B

Comment: Single and double equals are very different, use double or triple for comparison. Single sets. I'd also think you could do that `$row_rsPH['username'] == $row_GHall['pay1']` comparison in the SQL.

Comment: I used tripple but it works on the first record only

Comment: you should use `innerjoin` query here rather than comparing here

Comment: I don't know you haven't included much here. In the text you said you were thinking of using `single equal sign`. It'd probably be easiest to use SQL for the comparison.  Also we are left to guess if you are fetching correctly and what these variables contain.

Comment: I used single equal sign but it printed result of only TableA.record 1 on all usernames in Table B

Comment: Just to let you know, you shouldn't use empty() too, it will return `TRUE` if the given values are 0 or '0' even if they would be valid app / db values.